# Поиск следующего мероприятия по имеющимся данным в таблицах SQLite обо всех мероприятиях

Tags: android, sqlite, search, уведомления

Есть главная таблица `с именами всех заметок`, и для каждой заметки создаются две дополнительные таблицы содержащие:

1. Данные заметки.
2. Напоминания для них.

Имена этих таблиц: `имя_заметки + _текст`, `имя_заметки + _уведомления` соответственно.

---

*О функционале:*

1. *Сначала человек выбирает, когда будет мероприятие, аналогично Гугл Календарю, только с чуть большим функционалом для повторений мероприятий. Например, можно выбрать "Считая только определенное время в сутках" или "определенные дни недели".*
2. *Затем к мероприятиям применяются настройки к каждому из всех с учетом повторений и добавляются уведомления с выбором типа уведомления: будильник, оповещение и т.д. Причем можно добавить несколько уведомлений, например к мероприятию за сутки - оповещение, а с утра в день мероприятия - будильник. А также к каждому уведомлению можно добавить, когда оно будет (за определенное время до мероприятия, или в указанное время) и будет ли оно повторяться (также больше возможностей для повторения, имеется функция "считая только...").*

---

*Я нашел функции, которые схожи между собой, но все они предназначены для запуска кода через указанное время. Но это не эффективно, т.к. разряжает аккумулятор.*

Была идея сделать так, чтобы при срабатывании одного уведомления, программа находила в памяти и ставила один такой таймер на следующее уведомление. И это сработало.

---

**Как найти ближайшее следующее мероприятие, учитывая, что мероприятия и уведомления могут повторяться?**

---

*Если необходимо дополнить деталями, то я без проблем сделаю это. 
Заранее благодарю каждого за совет и идею!*

Comment: Сплошной текст - это зло, т.к. шанс того, что его прочтут до конца слишком мал. Учтите это в следующий раз.